# Was Venus actually in the desert?

Tags: plot-explanation, goddess-of-love

In the film, "[Goddess of Love](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3432552/)", the 'other woman' confronted Venus over the death of her cat, and then...

> chased Venus into the desert but then in the session with the psychiatrist  claimed never to have met
>  her. This leaves us with the suggestion that part of the scene was a hallucination...

Which portions of the desert scene (if any) were actually real?

Comment: Which Goddess of Love are you referring to?

Comment: @AndrewMartin There is a link in the question's text.  Please orient your mouse over the title of the film to locate the IMDB link, it's the 2015 film directed by John Knautz.  Big time under-rated film.

Comment: Whoops, missed that. Thanks. Thought it was the 88 film originally.

Comment: @AndrewMartin, sadly there are lots of reviews out there, but the net appears to be void of in-depth explanations.